# Скрипт не срабатывает через крон

Tags: cron, freebsd, mysql

Freebsd

```
crontab -e
```

Ввожу такую строчку:

```
0        17        *       *        1-5  mysql -uПользователь -pПасворд -hХост < /путь к скрипту/script.sql
```

В строке шелл все отрабатывает. Через крон не срабатывает - хоть тресни. Что же делать?
Крон от рута. В шелл все нормально отрабатывает, то есть с правами и доступом все в порядке. В кроне переход на след строку после введенного кода выполнен.

Comment: ==
спасибо за ответы, осталось только уточнить, что в freebsd mysql обычно валяется в : 
/usr/local/bin/mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте указать полный путь к mysql

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! )

Answer (score 1):

У crontab своё окружение. Возможно, просто не находится бинарник mysql, так как его нет в PATH для крона. Попробуйте указать полный путь до mysql. А вообще, [ошибки надо смотреть](http://zooom.com.ua/linux/poleznye-sovety-i-hitrosti/384-posylaem-pravilnye-otchyoty-o-vypolnii-skriptov-iz-cron.html), 99% вопросов отпадут :)